# Report Builder / BIDS - Running specific datasets only via parameter

Tags: reporting-services, report, bids, reportbuilder

We have a lot of reports delivered via SSRS.

We are now looking to consolidate these reports into 'packs' so that multiple reports will actually run in one .rdl.

We are using a separate dataset for each report and are looking to use a parameter to select which reports are run (i.e. which datasets to run)

Does anyone have any guidance on this, i would like to avoid using sub reports if possible.

Comment: Do you have access to the SubReport item in the toolbox?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to SubReports. I was hoping that we could use parameter driven packs.